# How to create a local Windows account with a Microsoft account?

Tags: c#, windows

If I have a Microsoft account, create a local windows account with a Microsoft account, what should I do? Currently I am able to create a local Windows user without using a Microsoft account.

I think it may be that when you create a local windows account with a Microsoft account, the two accounts will be bound.As the following code, you can directly create a local account without using a Microsoft account, even if you create a Microsoft account, it is just a local user.

```
public static void CreateLocalWindowsAccount_Standard()
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" +
                                    Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
                DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("TestUser_Standard", "user");
                NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test User from .NET" });
                NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "PasswordExpired", 1 });

                NewUser.CommitChanges();

                // Add the Account to a Group
                DirectoryEntry grp;
                grp = AD.Children.Find("Users", "group");
                if (grp != null)
                {
                    grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() });
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Standard Account Created Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

I want to be able to create a local windows account with a Microsoft account.